# How to assure that one out of 2 functions run first

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 functions bindclub() and displayevent(). I want to assure bindclub() to run first always.I have also tried to put both the functions in ng-init but it also does not assured to run bindclub() first

```
angular.module('app', []).controller("EventCtrl",EventController); 
EventController.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$window"]; 

function EventController($scope, $http, $window) {
     $scope.bindclub = function () {
            $http({
                url: '/Master/bindclub',
                method: 'post',

            }).then(function (response) {
                debugger
                $scope.clubidname = response.data;
            }, function () { alert("Error in binding club"); });
        }


        $scope.displayevent = function () {
            $http({
                url: '/Master/displayevent',
                method: 'post',

            }).then(function (response) {
                alert('Displayed');

            }, function () { alert('Error in display event'); });

        }
    $scope.bindclub ();
    $scope.displayevent ();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use callback function wait until `bindclub` function executing and then start `displayevent` function

```
angular.module('app', []).controller("EventCtrl", EventController);
    EventController.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$window"];

    function EventController($scope, $http, $window) {
        $scope.bindclub = function(callback) {
            $http({
                url: '/Master/bindclub',
                method: 'post',
            }).then(function(response) {
                debugger
                $scope.clubidname = response.data;
                callback() // callback function
            }, function() {
                alert("Error in binding club");
                callback()// callback function
            });
        }
        $scope.displayevent = function() {
            $http({
                url: '/Master/displayevent',
                method: 'post',
            }).then(function(response) {
                alert('Displayed');
            }, function() {
                alert('Error in display event');
            });
        }
        $scope.bindclub(function() {
            $scope.displayevent(); // this execute after bindclub fucntion
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the second event dependent on the first event? If yes then you may set it as a callback event of the first event, to ensure that it is triggered on the success of the first event.

Answer (score 0):

The function bindclub is indeed being run before displayevent. But these two functions themselves make http calls which have callbacks. There is no guarantee to have the callbacks executed in the order you want.

The only work around I see is to call the other function inside of the callback in bindclub.

The other way is for you to chain the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `displayEvent` to a custom event that is triggered inside the `bindEvent` callback.

Check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) post for example on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Return the promise and then chain them:

```
$scope.bindclub = function () {
    //vvvv RETURN httpPromise           
    return $http({
        url: '/Master/bindclub',
        method: 'post',

    }).then(function (response) {
        debugger
        $scope.clubidname = response.data;
    }, function () { alert("Error in binding club"); });
}

//CHAIN them
$scope.bindclub()
  .then(function () {
      $scope.displayevent();
});
```

Since the $http service returns a promise, the second operation can be chained from the first operation with the `.then` method of the first promise.